# Why is index not being used when 'Check X Min' flag is set to true?

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple query for a simple table in postgres. I have a simple index on that table.

In some environments it is using the index when performing the query, in other environments (on the same RDS instance, different database) it isn't. (checked using `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`)

One thing I've noticed is that if the 'Check X Min' flag on the index is TRUE then index is not used. (`pg_catalog.pg_index.indcheckxmin`)

How do I ensure the index is used and, presumably, have the 'Check X Min' flag set to false?

Table contains 100K+ rows.

Things I have tried:

- The index is valid and is always used in environments where the 'Check X Min' is set to false.
- `set enable_seqscan to off;` still does not use the index.
- Creating/recreating an index in these environments always seems to have 'Check X Min' set to true.
- Vacuuming does not seem to help.

Setup of table and index:

```
CREATE TABLE schema_1.table_1 (
    field_1 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    field_2 int4 NULL,
    field_3 timestamptz NULL,
    field_4 numeric(10,2) NULL
);
CREATE INDEX table_1_field_1_field_3_idx ON schema_1.table_1 USING btree (field_1, field_3 DESC);
```

Query:

```
select field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4
from schema_1.table_1
where field_1 = ’abcdef’
order by field_3 desc limit 1;
```

When not using index:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Limit  (cost=4.41..4.41 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=3.174..3.176 rows=1 loops=1)                                   |
  ->  Sort  (cost=4.41..4.42 rows=6 width=51) (actual time=3.174..3.174 rows=1 loops=1)                              |
        Sort Key: field_3 DESC                                                                                     |
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB                                                                    |
        ->  Seq Scan on table_1  (cost=0.00..4.38 rows=6 width=51) (actual time=3.119..3.150 rows=3 loops=1)|
              Filter: ((field_1)::text = 'abcdef'::text)                                                               |
              Rows Removed by Filter: 96                                                                             |
Planning time: 2.895 ms                                                                                              |
Execution time: 3.197 ms                                                                                             |
```

When using index:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Limit  (cost=0.28..6.30 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.070..0.144 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                      |
  ->  Index Scan using table_1_field_1_field_3_idx on field_1  (cost=0.28..12.31 rows=2 width=51) (actual time=0.049..0.066 rows=1 loops=1)|
        Index Cond: ((field_1)::text = 'abcdef'::text)                                                                                                    |
Planning time: 0.184 ms                                                                                                                                 |
Execution time: 0.303 ms                                                                                                                                |
```

*Have renamed fields, schema, and table to avoid sharing business context*

Comment: Please show the query, the table and index definition and the `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: Have updated indexed query plan to use the same data set and added table size (100K+ rows)

Comment: Most probably your statistics are out of date in the environments where the index isn't used. Does running `vacuum analyze schema_1.table_1;` change anything there?

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I tried this and nothing changed in the query plan - still does not use the index.

Comment: "The index is valid and is always used in environments where the 'Check X Min' is set to false."  This makes no sense.  "indcheckxmin" is part of the index, not part of the environment.  You can't have one environment where it is true and one where it is false for the same index.

Comment: *What is the problem?* I realize the performance of not using the index is an order of magnitude greater than using it. But it's still **only 6ms** (actually slightly less). That's 10000 executions to improve total performance by 1min. We should dream of having systems of tracking down 6ms inefficiencies. As @jjanes put it just "put up with the limitation". Move on to some bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY, and have long-open transactions.  From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY):

> Even then, however, the index may not be immediately usable for queries: in the worst case, it cannot be used as long as transactions exist that predate the start of the index build.

You don't have a lot of options here.  Hunt down and fix your long-open transactions, don't use CONCURRENTLY, or put up with the limitation.