# Parameters (attributes) of Postgres indexes (checking minima)

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, attributes, query-optimization

What is the attribute of the index "Checking minimums". How to disable the attribute. What does this attribute affect?Why is it on one index and not on the other

```
CREATE INDEX extendedreport_sparkid_w_idx ON extrep_mdm.extendedreport USING btree (sparkid) INCLUDE (inn, isacting) 
WHERE ((curr = 1) 
  AND ((okopf_codenew)::text !\~\* '755.*'::text) 
  AND (((okfs_code)::text = ANY ((ARRAY\['12'::character varying, '13'::character varying, '14'::character varying\])::text\[\])) OR ((okopf)::text \~* '.*Казенные.*|Государств.*|.Муницип.*|.*Бюджет.*'::text)) 
  AND ((okopf_codenew)::text !\~ '3000.*'::text) 
  AND ((fullnamerus)::text !\~* '.*НЕГОСУД.*'::text))


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX extr_sp_id_w_indx ON extrep_mdm.extendedreport USING btree (sparkid) INCLUDE (id) 
WHERE ((curr = 1) 
  AND ((isacting)::text \~\* '1|true'::text) 
  AND ((okopf_codenew)::text !\~\* '3000'::text))
```

[image: check]

[image: unchecked]

I tried to create in different ways, it does not work to remove this attribute when creating.

Comment: You will have to consult the manual of that unknown tool you are using, to find out what underlying Postgres index attribute they are referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the catalog view [`pg_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/catalog-pg-index.html) it seems that a column `indcheckxmin` (boolean) is shown on the screen.

It's documented as

> If true, queries must not use the index until the xmin of this pg_index row is below their TransactionXmin event horizon, because the table may contain broken HOT chains with incompatible rows that they can see

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192495/why-is-index-not-being-used-when-check-x-min-flag-is-set-to-true) may provide some hints how to resolve.

Comment: how can I complete all transactions on the prod DB - ? Kill all processes, may  hellp?  Before create index?